# keeping the shape of the graph, but change the color

Tags: r

I am using as_tbl_graph and ggraph to show the network relation data.
I wish to keep the shape and location of each node, while changing the color with several conditions.
Problem here is that every time I run the code, the full graph image changes at all.
Is there a way to keep the shape of the graph, but only change the color?
There are so many items so I can't designate each node's location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `layout` argument in `ggraph` to fix the graph structure, then change anything else you'd like. You can find more in the Details section of the `?ggraph` help page, in the `vigentte("Layouts", package = "ggraph")` and in articles [like this one](https://www.data-imaginist.com/2017/ggraph-introduction-layouts/).

```r
library(ggraph)
library(igraph) # for sample data

graph <- graph_from_data_frame(highschool)

ggraph(graph, layout = "kk") +
  geom_edge_link(aes(color = factor(year))) +
  geom_node_point()
```

[image]

Let's say you wanted something else, so we change the layout.

```r
p_stress <- ggraph(graph, layout = "stress") +
  geom_edge_link(aes(color = factor(year)))

p_stress + geom_node_point()
```

[image]
Okay, clearly it's different from our first graph using `layout = "kk"`. Now we can adjust the color and size of points (or whatever else we want) without changing the graph structure.

```r
p_stress + geom_node_point(color = "blue", size = 3)
```

[image]